# Jquery : add inner html to dynamically generated div

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code while try to change the inner html of the dynamically geneted div , the inner html dosent change.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'xxx.xxx',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#scroll_items').append('<div class="list_item more_content" align="center"><img src="loader.gif"></div>'); 
    },
    success: function(data) {    
      $('#scroll_items div:last').html("hai to all");    
    }
});
```

The html part

```
  <div id="scroll_items"> 
    <div class="list_item1">
    Scroll beyond this container to automatically load more content
    </div>
    <div class="list_item">
    [ List Item 2 ]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: also are you sure the success function is even firing?

Comment: i dont think success function s firing.

Comment: you have an error, u have extra curly brace, try after removing it.

Comment: Independant of the ajax call this works fine [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4uE3U/) - I think @shreedhar has it right, either it's the simple extra curly brace or your ajax call is failing.

Comment: Either your copy-paste skills are off or that's truly your script and html code

Comment: sorry for that , a curly braket came by mistake , i have corerected it @shreedhar and Prescott.The ajax success function is also firing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove one extra curly brace, it may work.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'xxx.xxx',
      beforeSend: function() {
         $('#scroll_items').append('<div class="list_item more_content" align="center"><img src="loader.gif"></div>');
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#scroll_items div:last').html("hai to all");
      }
    });
```

try this.

or try

```
success: function(data) {
setTimeout(function(){
        $('#scroll_items div:last').html("hai to all");
      },100);
   }
```

Comment: @pckabeer isn't working even after removing that curly brace?

Comment: that curly bracket was a mistake that happened while i typed it here

Comment: try giving some timeout duration inside the success function, it may work

Comment: lemme check , but this is a potion a bit more long code , i will paste that code here

Comment: when was it working? after removing curly brace or after giving timeout?